# Can't get exact position of BSTR data in VARIANT struct

Tags: c++, variant, bstr

I have strange problem with reading **`BSTR`** value from a **`VARIANT`** struct.

I use following Javascript code to send data to C++ code:

```
external.CppCall("zhttShow", 1, "Y");
```

In an `Invoke` function in my C++ code, I tried to access that data:

```
HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE WebBrowser::Invoke(_In_  DISPID dispIdMember, _In_  REFIID  riid, _In_  LCID lcid, _In_  WORD wFlags, _In_  DISPPARAMS *pp, _Out_opt_ VARIANT *pVarResult, _Out_opt_ EXCEPINFO *pExcepInfo, _Out_opt_ UINT *puArgErr)
{
    if (dispIdMember == 100)
    {
        unsigned int k = pp->cArgs;
        if (k > 0)
        {
            VARIANT *vVariant = &pp->rgvarg[k - 1];
            if ((vVariant->vt & VT_BSTR) == VT_BSTR && vVariant->pvarVal->bstrVal)
            {
                wchar_t *wide = (wchar_t*)(vVariant->pvarVal->bstrVal);
                // other code
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In above code, **`wide`** point to undefined position. If I get pointer of **`vVariant->pvarVal->bstrVal`** it point to a position near the BSTR value:

```
VARIANT *vVariant = &pp->rgvarg[k - 1];
if ((vVariant->vt & VT_BSTR) == VT_BSTR && vVariant->pvarVal->bstrVal)
{
    wchar_t *wide = (wchar_t*)(&vVariant->pvarVal->bstrVal);
    // other code
}
```

**`wide`** point to the position behide the **`BSTR`** data 8 bytes, so instead get **"zhttShow"** string, I only get **"Show"**. If I subtract **`wide`** by 4 I will get desired data.

Bellow is debug screen for the second C++ code:

[image]

## Question:

Why **`wide`** doesn't point to the BSTR's exact position? What is the error in my code and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `BSTR` is not a `wchar_t*`. It may look similar, but is not. And more importanlty, a `wchar_t*` is definitely not a `BSTR`. BSTRs have structure, a header that sits in *front* of the pointed-to value, so the real BSTR starts few bytes *before* the address. See [BSTR Data Type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms221069.aspx):

> A BSTR is a composite data type that consists of a **length prefix**, a data string, and a terminator.

This is why you should always use appropriate BSTR specific APIs. Best, use compiler support like [`_bstr_t`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zthfhkd6.aspx). To extract the BSTR from VARIANT correctly I would use a [`_variant_t` Extractor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/variant-t-extractors). Let the compiler deal with the details.